# Create and integrate a Help File for WPF vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, chm, helpfile

I would like to implement a F1 help/user guide for my WPF MVVM vb.net project but I can't seem to even create a project for it.

So I've done some searching and a lot of answers to this question on here are over 5 years old and most of the links are broken so I'd like to get a more up-to-date answer.

I also found this msdn page, which talks all about a HTML help project (.hhp) in visual studio, yet I cannot seem to find it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms524279(v=vs.85).aspx

My life is also made that bit harder by the fact that the PC I write code on isn't connected to the internet.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternate way to do this. When you press **F1** key on the keyboard , an addition window with a tree structure comes of. That is totally written in HTML and CSS.

Have a look at [Microsoft HTML Help Workshop](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21138).

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can use this to create a help file, not the nicest software to use but it seems to do the job. Any documentation on implementation into a wpf project?

Comment: @Robert you have to write alot for this. You need to use HTML tags for your texts appearing in the window. Create a complete help file and the mapping with F1 key can be done programatically. It can be made context sensitive also but that purely through code

Comment: So, help authoring and connecting the CHM help file to a application isn't a easy way. Please try to learn creating CHM files. You may want to use a tool like FAR HTML. See my web site at www.help-info.de